# Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Been stuck at this trying to delete data from the database, I'm clearly lost with the logic somewhere I'd grately appreciate any assistance.

resume-detail.html:

```
<div class="row">
            {% if educations %}
            {% for education in educations %}
            <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 pt-2">
              <div class="component-wrapper rounded shadow">
                <div class="p-4 border-bottom bg-light">
                  <h4 class="title mb-0">{{education.institution}}</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="p-4">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <p><strong>Qualification: </strong> {{education.qualification}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                      <p><strong>Level of Qualification: </strong> {{education.level}}</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">                    
                  <div class="col">
                      <a href="{% url 'delete' educations.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Qualification </a>
                      <!-- <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete Qualification</button> -->
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 pt-2">
                    <h4 class="text-dark"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-outline btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEducation"><span class="mr-2">+</span> Add Education</button></h4>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

i'm using a modal to capture this data

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addEducation" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addEducationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <form action=""  method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}....
```

urls.py

```
    path('userapp/view/<slug:slug>/', user_views.resume_detail, name='resume-detail'),
    path('delete/<str:id>/', user_views.delete_view, name='delete' )
```

views.py

```
def delete_view(request, id):
    
    obj  = Resume.objects.get(id = id)

    if request.method =="POST":
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Information Deleted Successfully")
        
        return redirect('resume-detail', id = id)

    educations = Education.objects.get(resume = obj)
    experiences = Experience.objects.get(resume = obj)

    context = {}
    context['object'] = obj
    context['educations'] = educations
    context['experiences'] = experiences

    return render(request, 'resume-detail.html', context)
```

I would like to delete data for educations and experiences. Its the data I capture with the modals. What could I be doing wrong ?

models.py

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    uniqueId = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, default=OTHER, max_length=200)
    marital_status = models.CharField(choices=MARITAL_CHOICES, default=SINGLE, max_length=200)
    addressLine1 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    addressLine2 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    village = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, choices=DISTRICT_CHOICES, default=KAMPALA, max_length=200)
    district = models.CharField(choices=DISTRICT_CHOICES, default=KAMPALA, max_length=100)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_letter = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes', null=True, blank=True,)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes', null=True, blank=True,)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.uniqueId)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('resume-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.uniqueId is None:
            self.uniqueId = str(uuid4()).split('-')[0]

            self.slug = slugify('{} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.uniqueId))

        if self.image == 'default.jpg':
            self.image = random.choice(self.IMAGES)        
        self.slug = slugify('{} {} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.uniqueId))
        super(Resume, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Education(models.Model):
    institution = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    qualification = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    level = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default=LEVEL5A, max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    graduated = models.DateField()
    major_subject = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} for {} {}'.format(self.qualification, self.resume.user.first_name, self.resume.user.last_name)

class Experience(models.Model):

    company = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=200)
    position = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date  = models.DateField()
    experience = models.TextField()
    skills = models.TextField()
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} at {}'.format(self.position, self.company)
```

Comment: Is the `urls.py` an app URLs file or the general project (the one in next to settings.py)  URLs file? Also you have to pass the slug as `slug=educations.slug`.

Comment: It is the URL file for the project

Comment: Also there is a difference between a slug and id `obj  = Resume.objects.get(id = slug)`. Usually a slug is a unique string representation where as id is a unique db index integer representation, so you can filter id by string such as "1" or "2", but not by slug: "some-slug" unless you have some modifications to the `Resume` model that you have not included in the question.

Comment: Make sure your `educations` object  has `slug` attribute.

Comment: @antpngl92 I have a slugField in my Resume model

Comment: @EzonZhao kindly show me an example of what you mean.

Comment: Post your `Resume` model so we can give an accurate answer instead of guessing what you have. 
> I have a slugField in my Resume model  => then filter by slug not an ID

Comment: @EzonZhao that is wrong, he does not need a slug in the `Education` model.

Comment: Share your `Resume` model.

Comment: I've edited my post and included the Resume model @SunderamDubey

Comment: What is `educations.slug` in url you are sending in the view to delete it? slug is no field in `Education` model.

Comment: Send `educations.id` then get the object in the view and delete it.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Should I include a slugfield in the Education and Experience classes?

Comment: You are using `educations.slug` in your `url` template tag, and this is where django error complains. If `slug` is an attribute of `Resume`, you might want to use `url 'delete' obj.slug` instead

Comment: Are you getting `Resume` instance for deletion?

Comment: See below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73472816/17562044).

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `id` which is primary key in the `Education` model, so:

```html
<form action="{% url 'delete' educations.id %}"  method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}....
```

Add `education` as ForeignKey in the model, so:

```py
class Resume(models.Model):
    education=models.ForeignKey(Education,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Change the url as:

```py
path('userapp/view/<int:id>/', user_views.resume_detail, name='resume-detail'),
path('delete/<int:id>/', user_views.delete_view, name='delete' )
```

Then in view, get the object through `id` then delete it.

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def delete_view(request, id):
    education_instance=get_object_or_404(Education,id=id)
    
    obj  = get_object_or_404(Resume, education=education_instance)


    if request.method =="POST":
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Information Deleted Successfully")
        
        return redirect('resume-detail', id=id)

    educations = get_object_or_404(Education, resume=obj)
    experiences = get_object_or_404(Experience,resume=obj)

    context = {}
    context['object'] = obj
    context['educations'] = educations
    context['experiences'] = experiences

    return render(request, 'resume-detail.html', context)
```

> `Note:` Generally, it is better to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of `get()` as it *calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises [Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404) instead of the model’s [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) exception*.

Comment: i've tried this however in my resume-detail.html page i'm being pointed to this "<a href="{% url 'delete' educations.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Qualification </a>" which should be the delete button. i'm thinking it has something to do with educations.id

Comment: @Muhumuza But you haven't defined any relationship like foreign key for this. If you want to fetch resume instance from `educations.id` then define a education field as foreign key in `Resume` model then the answer will work.

Comment: In Education and Experience classes i used resume as the foreignkey. Should I be doing it differently ?

Comment: @Muhumuza Let me update the answer.

Comment: @Muhumuza Check updated answer.

Comment: @Muhumuza I think it should be `education.id` in action attribute for particular instance.

Comment: It says Education is not defined so I cant effect the migrations. However resume is a foreign key already in the Education class. Should that relationship already be enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247511/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-muhumuza).

Answer (score 0):

As @SunderamDubey said, if you need objects `Education` and `Experience` based by the `Resume` relation - edit your `urls.py` path to accept `delete/<int:resume_pk>` instead of `delete/<str:slug>/`.

Then:

```
# urls.py 
    path('delete/<int:resume_pk>/', user_views.delete_view, name='delete')
```

```
# views.py
def delete_view(request, resume_pk):
    
    obj  = Resume.objects.get(id=resume_pk)
    
    ...
    
    educations = Education.objects.get(resume=obj)
    experiences = Experience.objects.get(resume=obj)
    ...
```

```
# modal 
<form action="{% url 'delete' resume_pk=obj.pk %}"  method="POST">
```